# How to parse files and create tags in eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse

I'm new to eclipse. I have a ~100 MB code base which I have added in Eclipse and ran indexer to parse the files. It took some time to index the files. But I'm not able to see definition or call hierarchy of any function call. What am I missing? I just want to parse files for static analysis like we do "Synchronize files" in Source insight.

Comment: you have to include the CDT in your eclipse

Comment: @PeterMiehle: Sorry for the late response. Could you please elaborate on that? I can see the project directories in Project explorer pane on the left. The files are indexed, but I cannot see the call hierarchy of any function. Something is missing which I'm unable to figure out. I'd be glad if you could help.

Comment: have you installed the C-Developer-Toolkit?

Comment: @PeterMiehle: Yes after reading your comment I had installed that. Seems like I wasn't having all the macros defined in Project path and symbols, so I did that and now it's able to index all the code.